# How to create this signup form - NativeScript GridView

Tags: nativescript

I am new to NativeScript, and am overwhelmed at the moment.

I am trying to get this layout (pictured below) just in a skeleton form, so I can learn and fill in the details.

Starting at the top, it appears I need a grid of 8 rows, and 2 columns.

```
  <GridLayout rows="*, auto" columns="250, *">
    <Label text="First Name" />
    <Label text="Middle Initial" col="1" />

<TextField hint="First Name"         
        secure="false"
        autocorrect="false"
        maxLength="10"
        class="input input-border"/>

    <TextField hint="Middle Initial"         
        secure="false"
        autocorrect="false"
        maxLength="1"
        class="input input-border"/>

<!-- continue... -->

    <Label text="This is Label in row 0, col 0" rowSpan="2" colSpan="2" />
  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

This method is not working. The layout does not reflect what I need in the image.

Can you please help me to at least rough out this layout? I am having a heck of a time.

Thank you for looking.

[image: Ideal Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form may look something like this,

```
 <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <Label class="m-5 h2" text="1. Lets create your account"></Label>
        <GridLayout columns="*,*">
            <StackLayout col="0" class="m-5">
                <Label text="First Name"></Label>
                <TextField class="input input-border"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout col="1" class="m-5">
                <Label text="Last Name"></Label>
                <TextField class="input input-border"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout columns="*,*">
            <StackLayout col="0" class="m-5">
                <Label text="Email Address"></Label>
                <TextField class="input input-border"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout col="1" class="m-5">
                <Label text="Birth month and year"></Label>
                <TextField class="input input-border"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Learn more about layouts at https://www.nslayouts.com/

Answer (score 1):

for something like this I would wrap the outermost element with

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout>
  <!-- Main form component wrapper -->
  <!-- Green component wrapper -->
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

That will make your layout scrollable and the elements will be placed on top of one another without needing to specify a fixed size.

For the main form area I would use a layout something like this

```
<GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
  <!-- this stackLayout is the lefthand side of form -->
  <StackLayout row="0" col="0">
    <TextField ... />
    <TextField ... />
  </StackLayout>

  <!-- this stackLayout is the righthand side of form -->
  <StackLayout row="0" col="1">
    <Switch .../>
    <Birthday stuff... />
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

This would split the upper area into two columns and stack the fields on top of one another.

The green area is probably easiest as one `StackLayout` with `backgroundColor="someGreenColor"` and then using either `GridLayout` or `AbsoluteLayout` I would code in the three boxes with a lot of css.

Hope that helps!